# handling outlier cases for tictactoe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I need help with the outlier cases. I have mentioned below where the cases are failing.

````
possibleTurns = ("A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3")
movesUsed = []

def main():    
    players = ["X","O"]
    while len(movesUsed) <9:
        #Player 1 Move
        turnp1 = input(f"Choose a move Player 1: ")
        print(f"Your move was: {turnp1}")
        validMove = analyzeMove(turnp1)
        move(validMove,players[0])
        score()
        movesUsed.append(validMove)
        #Player 2 Move
        turnp2 = input(f"Choose a move Player 2: ")
        print(f"Your move was: {turnp2}")
        validMove = analyzeMove(turnp2)
        move(validMove,players[1])
        score()
        movesUsed.append(validMove)```

def analyzeMove(themove):
    if themove.upper() in possibleTurns:
        return themove
    # This works but it switches the turn to player 1 even if its player 2 who makes a mistake.
    if themove.upper() not in possibleTurns:
        print("Invalid Move")
        main()
    # A used move will replace the old move so an X A1 will become O if O is chosen in error.
    if themove.upper() in movesUsed:
        print("That move was used!")
        main()
````

Comment: Don't use recursion as a replacement for looping. When you recurse, it starts over at player 1's turn.

Comment: So i should use a for loop? but how can i verify that the input is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `main()` recursively, it always starts at player 1's turn.

Instead of recursing when the input is invalid, use a `while` loop to keep asking for input until it's valid. `analyzeMove` can return `False` to indicate that the move isn't valid, and the loop asks again.

Another bug is that `analyzeMove()` checks if the move is in `possibleTurns` before checking if it has already been used.

Also, rather than duplicating all the code for player 1 and 2, use a variable to indicate whose turn it is.

```
possibleTurns = ("A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3")
movesUsed = []

def main():    
    players = ["X","O"]
    cur_player = 0
    while len(movesUsed) < 9:
        while True:
            turnp1 = input(f"Choose a move Player {cur_player+1}: ")
            print(f"Your move was: {turnp1}")
            validMove = analyzeMove(turnp1)
            if validMove:
                break
        move(validMove,players[cur_player])
        score()
        movesUsed.append(validMove)
        cur_player = 1 if cur_player == 0 else 0

def analyzeMove(themove):
    if themove.upper() in movesUsed:
        print("That move was used!")
        return False
    if themove.upper() in possibleTurns:
        return themove
    else:
        print("Invalid Move")
        return False
```

Comment: does the if valid move: break accept a valid move right? And in  cur_player = 1 if cur_player == 0 else 0, the else 0 resets the cur_player == 2 to 0?

Comment: 1. Yes. Any non-empty string is truthy. 2. How would `cur_player` ever become 2? If it's 0 it changes to 1, otherwise it changes to 0.

Comment: Right I meant 1, the {cur_player+1} confused me, i didn't know you can add to a variable after in a f string.

Comment: You can put any expression in an f-string.